# HttpURLConnection sends a POST request even though httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET"); is set

Tags: java, http, urlconnection

Here is my code:

```
String addr = "http://172.26.41.18:8080/domain/list";

URL url = new URL(addr);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setDoInput(true);
httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
httpCon.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpCon.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW4fYFgjkl5463");

httpCon.connect();

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());

System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());

out.close();
```

What I see in response:

> 500 Server error

I open my `httpCon` var, and what I see:

> POST /rest/platform/domain/list HTTP/1.1

Why is it set to POST even though I have used `httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");` to set it to GET?

Comment: Does the basic authentication travel over the wire via POST?

Comment: Were you testing on a Galaxy Nexus? `httpCon.setDoOutput(true);` forced POST on my Galaxy Nexus but not on the Galaxy S2 running Gingerbread.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `httpCon.setDoOutput(true);` implicitly set the request method to POST because that's the default method whenever you want to send a request body.

If you want to use GET, remove that line and remove the `OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());` line. You don't need to send a request body for GET requests.

The following should do for a simple GET request:

```
String addr = "http://172.26.41.18:8080/domain/list";
URL url = new URL(addr);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
httpCon.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
httpCon.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW4fYFgjkl5463");
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
```

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the password part of your `Authorization` header value doesn't seem to be properly Base64-encoded. Perhaps it's scrambled because it was examplary, but even if it wasn't I'd fix your Base64 encoding approach.

Comment: AFAIK, the REST does not mandate GET not having a request body and there maybe legitimate requests with a body.

Comment: @mirage: That's not specified by REST and would be just ignored. Only badly implemented servers/APIs might require it. This should never be relied upon.

Comment: but does it mean that this is prohibited? I mean, HttpURLConnection seems to prohibit the use of GET with bodies, but is this non-standard? There are many libraries which allow it's use.

Comment: @BalusC Couldin't find any proof in the Java source code that `httpCon.setDoOutput(true);` sets the method to POST.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java/#1261

Comment: @BalusC thanks! I expected it to happen directly in `setDoOutput`.