# Calling HTTP API Using Java to send SMS

Tags: java, android, rest, soap, http-headers

I have attached my HTTP Class now i need to make a call to this class when ever i need to send my SMS on button click. I seem not to find any solution. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
    public class Sender {
    // Username that is to be used for submission
    String username;
    // password that is to be used along with username
    String password;
    // Message content that is to be transmitted
    String message;
    /**
     * What type of the message that is to be sent
     * <ul>
     * <li>0:means plain text</li>
     * <li>1:means flash</li>
     * <li>2:means Unicode (Message content should be in Hex)</li>
     * <li>6:means Unicode Flash (Message content should be in Hex)</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    String type;
    /**
     * Require DLR or not
     * <ul>
     * <li>0:means DLR is not Required</li>
     * <li>1:means DLR is Required</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    String dlr;
    /**
     * Destinations to which message is to be sent For submitting more than one
     * destination at once destinations should be comma separated Like
     * 91999000123,91999000124
     */
    String destination;
    // Sender Id to be used for submitting the message
    String source;
    // To what server you need to connect to for submission
    String server;
    // Port that is to be used like 8080 or 8000
    int port;
    public Sender(String server, int port, String username, String password,
                  String message, String dlr, String type, String destination,
                  String source) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.message = message;
        this.dlr = dlr;
        this.type = type;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.source = source;
        this.server = server;
        this.port = port;
    }
    private void submitMessage() {
        try {
             // Url that will be called to submit the message
            URL sendUrl = new URL("http://" + this.server + ":" + this.port
                    + "/bulksms/bulksms");
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) sendUrl
                    .openConnection();
              // This method sets the method type to POST so that
                // will be send as a POST request
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // This method is set as true wince we intend to send
             // input to the server
            httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
        // This method implies that we intend to receive data from server                                                         httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
// Implies do not use cached data
            httpConnection.setUseCaches(false);
         // Data that will be sent over the stream to the server.
            DataOutputStream dataStreamToServer = new DataOutputStream(
                    httpConnection.getOutputStream());
            dataStreamToServer.writeBytes("username="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8") +    "&password="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8") + "&type="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(this.type, "UTF-8") + "&dlr="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(this.dlr, "UTF-8") + "&destination="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(this.destination, "UTF-8") + "&source="

                    + URLEncoder.encode(this.source, "UTF-8") + "&message="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(this.message, "UTF-8"));
            dataStreamToServer.flush();
            dataStreamToServer.close();
           // Here take the output value of the server.
            BufferedReader dataStreamFromUrl = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
            String dataFromUrl = "", dataBuffer = "";
            // Writing information from the stream to the buffer
            while ((dataBuffer = dataStreamFromUrl.readLine()) != null) {
                dataFromUrl += dataBuffer;
            }
   /**
     * Now dataFromUrl variable contains the Response received from the
     * server so we can parse the response and process it accordingly.
    */
            dataStreamFromUrl.close();
            System.out.println("Response: " + dataFromUrl);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void main(String[] args) {
        try {
 // Below exmaple is for sending Plain text
            Sender s = new   Sender("http:", 8080, "xxxxxxx",
                    "xxxxx", "Congratulations! You just gave someone a priceless gift - LIFE! Thank you for donating." +
                    "Your next donation date is 13/6/16. Get ", "1", "0", "xxxxxxx",
                    "xxxx");
            s.submitMessage();
       // Below exmaple is for sending unicode
            Sender s1 = new Sender("smpp2.routesms.com", 8080, "xxxx",
                    "xxx", convertToUnicode("test for unicode").toString(),
                    "1", "2", "919869533416", "Update");
            s1.submitMessage();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    /**
     * Below method converts the unicode to hex value
     * @param regText
     * @return
     */
    private StringBuffer convertToUnicode(String regText) {
        char[] chars = regText.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            String iniHexString = Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]);
            if (iniHexString.length() == 1) {
                iniHexString = "000" + iniHexString;
            }
            else if (iniHexString.length() == 2)
                iniHexString = "00" + iniHexString;
            else if (iniHexString.length() == 3)
                iniHexString = "0" + iniHexString;
            hexString.append(iniHexString);
        }
        System.out.println(hexString);
        return hexString;
    }
}
```

I cant seem to call this class from Android app to send sms via the sms APi i have attached.

I have attached my call to the sender class to make a call to the http class when i want to send an SMS on button click.
             Button button;
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noBtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

```
            //createUserAppointment();

            Sender sender = new Sender("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 8080, "xxxxx",
                    "xxxx", "Congratulations! You just gave someone a priceless gift - LIFE! Thank you for donating." +
                    "Your next donation date is 13/6/16.", "1", "0", "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "Moja");
            sender.submitMessage();


        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what produces your attempt? An error? Or it compiles well but does'nt do anything? Please share any output too

Well you put "xxxxxxxxx" in args because you don't want us to see the real adress or because you are just copy pasting the example?

Otherwise I'd suggest you to take a look here 
[I am trying http connection over android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439235/i-am-trying-http-connection-over-android)

Comment: i manage to fix that with your solution but this time i am getting invalid value in username and password. the same username and password is what i use to login to send my bulk sms. i have on idea on this one.

Comment: i manage to fix that as well. i was using the wrong server name for the call. got the right server name from the API provider.